# VB.Net or C#. Represent a class as an array

Tags: c#, vb.net, mongodb

Is there a way to represent a class as an array?

For example, if we have the class A which has 2 fields, can we represent it as an array, containing the values of each field.

I tried doing that in my MongoDB class mapping (using `cm.GetMemberMap(Function(cx) cx.memberWithFields).SetRepresentation(MongoDB.Bson.BsonType.Array)` ). But it doesn't seem to work.

And my class also wont serialize because i haven't given it an Id, because I don't want to treat it as a seperate object with an id.

So my question is, can I serialize this class that I have ( which represents `memberWithFields` ) so that it's just an array ?

Comment: Check whether indexer property ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx ) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you need this to work with mongoDB?

Comment: Yes I needed this to work with mongoDB, not plain indexes. Anyway I got it to work.

Comment: You need to read about Reflection